# Hide a div while page is loading?

Tags: jquery

So I've got one div that loads kind of funny, and my client is a little concerned about it, but I want to help them out.

Is there a way I can hide a div for a set time with jQuery? probably just opacity: 0 on page load, then 2 seconds in, change it to opacity: 1.

An alternative might be to add/remove class method. I'm just not sure what the code would be to have it in one state while the page loads, then in the other state indefinitely (unless the page is refreshed of course) so something like

```
jQuery('#DIV').WHILELOADING(function() {
    jQuery('#DIV').addClass('hidden_div')
});

jQuery('#DIV').AFTER_2_SECONDS(function() {
    jQuery('#DIV').removeClass('hidden_div')
});
```

I'm just not 'entirely' sure how to do this. As well, a "loading screen" which I know how to do, is out of the question, lol. :P

Comment: How do you load this div? Is it page load? The answer depends on how you load the DIV. If you are using .load, then you can hide the div initially and then use .load callback to show the div.

Comment: It's just loaded by PHP generated HTML, not jQuery. I am following the first comment, so something like this? "jQuery('#DIV').delay(1000).removeClass('hidden_div');" ?

Comment: @Des If it is php generated code then echo the `removeClass` code at the end of the generating code.

Comment: @Des I'd seriously reconsider using a DIV hidden through CSS.  If the user doesn't have js enabled they will NEVER see the content.  Unless this isn't a concern.

Comment: I do appreciate the concern on this, but most people have JS enabled, as well as it's a jQuery setup that I'm hiding. It's not pertinent to the end user, just a nicety, so I'm alright if 1% of their visitors (probably less) can't see it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How is the div is being loaded, If it is page load then simply have the div hidden on page load and show the div inside

```
  jQuery(window).load (function () { 
      jQuery('#DIV').removeClass('hidden_div')
  });
```

If you are loading the div using `.load` (ajax call) then used .load callback to show the div.

```
jQuery('#DIV').load('<URL>', function() {
   jQuery('#DIV').removeClass('hidden_div')
});
```

Above two as assuming that you have the `div` hidden like below,

```
<div id="DIV" class="hidden_div"><!-- div content --> </div>
```

**Note:** Adding delay may not give you a consistent result. For ex: If the delay is 5 sec and page take 10 secs to load then you going to have the same issue.

> It's just loaded by PHP generated HTML, not jQuery. I am following the
>   first comment, so something like this?
>   "jQuery('#DIV').delay(1000).removeClass('hidden_div');"

If it is php generated code then echo the `removeClass` code at the end of the generating code.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid a flicker while loading, I'd recommend doing the initial hide with CSS

```
#div { display: none; }
```

Then to display the div use JS

```
function showDiv() {
    $('#div').show();
}

setTimeout(showDiv, 2000);
```

Comment: If you hide it through CSS if the user doesn't have js enabled the user will NEVER see the content...

Comment: It's a jQuery slider anyways, so I'm not overly concerned. As well, their target market, 99% of people have JS on

Answer (score 2):

Initially you can hide it via jquery (or CSS but thats something most folks don't like doing) and then call the show method once the page is done loading
You can try wrapping it in:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#DIV").hide();
    }
```

and then towards the bottom of your page (though it doesn't matter where really):

```
  $(window).load(function(){
    $("#DIV").show(); or .fadeIn();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#div')
    .css({opacity:0}) /*set opacity to 0*/
    .delay(2E0) /*wait 2 seconds*/
    .animate({opacity:1}); /*animate in opacity*/

});
```

alternatively,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#div')
    .css({opacity:0}) /*set opacity to 0*/

  //wait for body to load
  $('body').bind('load', function(){
    $('#div').animate({opacity:1}); /*animate in opacity*/
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is from jquery api website on [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

```
$('#myDiv').slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NNQ4f/

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the display property of the div inline to 'none' and then when the document has loaded show the div?

```
<div id="mydiv" style="display:none;"> </div>



$(document).ready(function() {
$('#mydiv').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would hide the div initially, then you can set a timer to remove the class or use .fadeTo to show it slowly (other finagling, not just swap to it, you also have to set opacity settings).  But, in my personal opinion I think it may be that the page could use to be reworked to look right the first time or find some other non-clock oriented timing scheme to change the view after an even happens.

Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function (){
    setTimeout($('#DIV').removeClass('hide'), 3000);
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    div#DIV .hide {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>

[...]

<div id="DIV" class="hide"></div>
```

Syntax *not* verified.

Cheers,
~M

Comment: If you hide it through CSS if the user doesn't have js enabled the user will NEVER see the content...

Comment: Ahh good point.  Yes, use .addclass to hide, not an class attribute of hide.

Answer (score 0):

First, set the content for non js users:

```
<body class="no-js">
  <div id="div">Content</div>
</body>
```

Then, remove class and show container.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Remove no js class
  $('body').removeClass('no-js');
  // Show and animate div container
  $('#div').hide().delay(2000).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: How is js going to remove the "no-js" class if there isn't js?  Just add the class as soon as the DOM is loaded.

Comment: If there is no js available, the "no-js"-class stays at the body, making it possible to style elements exclusively for non js users at first. The other way, some users with deactivated js would never see the #div container. EDIT: Css styling was not necessary, so i removed it for this example.

Comment: the CSS you removed was styled as `display:none` which is why I posted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/E8W8g/)

I'd use `$(document).ready();` to add you're css class and then `$(window).load();` to remove it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#DIV').addClass('hidden_div');
});
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#DIV').removeClass('hidden_div');
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

All the methods here are not working, I tested them. Jquery is just too slow to hide something before the user can see it, because the code must be in a DOM ready function. Easiest best and fastest way: Put the element that needs to be hidden in a div and add a js in the top of this div to hide it during loding, this way is also safe for users without js enabled! (tested in ie, chrome, ff, latest version 05.2013):

Example to hide a div:

```
<div id="content">
     <script type="text/javascript">
          // Get the div and hide it
          var div = document.getElementById('content');
          div.style.display = 'none';
          //Shows the div as soon as the page is loaded
          window.onload = function () {
          div.style.display = 'block';}
     </script>
     // Content that needs to be hidden
</div>
```

Cheers