# How to hide the video when website loads?

Tags: javascript, html

I want the embedded video to load HIDE when the website loads.

Can you help me with this. thanks. Im not really good in programming so I need all the help, but i know basic stuff.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $(".btn1").click(function(){ 
        $("p").slideUp();
      });
      $(".btn2").click(function(){
        $("p").slideDown();
      });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p><iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/b8B1O0Fak5s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
    <button class="btn1">Slide up</button>
    <button class="btn2">Slide down</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a delayed function.

I also think you may find your answer here
[Hide a div while page is loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744760/hide-a-div-while-page-is-loading)

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(window).load (function () { 
   jQuery('#DIV').removeClass('hidden_div')
});
```

**CSS**

```
div.hidden_div { display: none }
```

The following above will remove the class and therefor showing the element when page has finished loading.

Comment: Hi user3218338, I dont know how to do this one, im not a programmer I just know basic stuff html. Can you help me with this one with the rest of the codes. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$("p iframe").hide();
```

Or just give it a style:

```
iframe {
    style: display: none;
}
```

Comment: hi tyme thankyou for fast reply. But i dont know how to do this. Im not a programmer so I need you to be specific. thanks

Comment: Either put the jQuery code in the `script` tags, or make some `style` tags and add the `iframe` style above - @user3480984

Comment: I dont really know what your talking about, can you do this for me? sorry about this. and besides I will just put this to my blogger post manually. thankx